# Dynamically add new option to <select> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code in my MVC5 app which fills several `SelectList` and then passes them from my Controller via the `ViewBag` to my View

**Controller**:

```
        // GET: INV_Assets/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            INV_Assets iNV_Assets = await db.INV_Assets.FindAsync(id);
            if (iNV_Assets == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_dept", iNV_Assets.Location_Id);
            ViewBag.Manufacturer_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Manufacturers, "Id", "manufacturer_description", iNV_Assets.Manufacturer_Id);
            ViewBag.Model_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description", iNV_Assets.Model_Id);
            ViewBag.Status_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Statuses, "Id", "status_description", iNV_Assets.Status_Id);
            ViewBag.Type_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Types, "Id", "type_description", iNV_Assets.Type_Id);
            ViewBag.Vendor_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Vendors, "Id", "vendor_name", iNV_Assets.Vendor_Id);
            return View(iNV_Assets);
        }
```

**View**:

```
@model Tracker.Models.INV_Assets

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select.dropdown').append('<option>' + "<<< Add New >>>" + '</option');
</script>


<h3>Edit Asset @Model.Id</h3>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model_Id, "Model_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <span class="control-label col-md-2">Model:</span>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Model_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

.....
```

This renders the following (just one for example):

```
<select class="form-control dropdown valid" id="Model_Id" name="Model_Id">     
    <option selected="selected" value="1">XTERAV12</option>
    <option value="2">5330</option>
    <option value="3">Sunblade 6000</option>
    <option value="4">DV7650</option>
    <option value="5">R40</option>
    <option value="6">A1396</option>
    <option value="7">Inspiron 3646</option>
</select>
```

What I'm attempting to do now is (once the page is ready) use jQuery to add an option for "<<< ADD NEW >>>" at the TOP of each one of my  groups.

To try this, I added a class titled "dropdown" to my first `@Html.DropDownList()` on my view. Then in my script, I'm attempting to select all with the `.dropdown` class and add the desired . When I refresh my page, nothing happens. However (in Google Chrome) if I use the same code `$('select.dropdown').append('<option>' + "<<< Add New >>>" + '</option');` within my `Console` window, the option is added at the bottom of the list.

Can anyone help with this? Why is it working in the Browser Console but not on load itself?

When the page loads I'm trying to get the "<<< ADD NEW >>>" as the top of each one of the  list, and then I want to (on click) popup my Create() View for the relevant list (Location, Manufacturer, etc.)

Comment: First there is an overload of `DropDownListFor()` that add a label option - `@Html.DrownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, YourSelectList, "<< AddNew >>")` (no need for jquery). Second, there is no point using the the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor as you have done (the selected item will be the value of the property so its ignored). Third, you cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`

Comment: Then, in order to show you 'popup', you will need to handle the `.change` event of the `select`

Comment: Thanks for replying Stephen, but you seem to be going over my head a little. I'm lost as to what you are referring to with your 2nd/3rd points.

Comment: It should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.ID_List, "<< ADD NEW >>")` and in the controller `ViewBag.ID_List = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description")`

Comment: I see there is an overload for `object htmlAttributes`, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct on my View: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, ViewBag.Model_Id, "<<< CREATE NEW >>>", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown"})`. **Error**: *'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<InvTracker.Models.INV_Assets>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name`*.

Comment: Please read my first and last comment. You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the SelectList

Comment: I now have `ViewBag.Model_List = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description");` in my Controller, and `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model_Id, ViewBag.Model_List, "<<< CREATE NEW >>>", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })` for my View but am getting the same error...?

Comment: `ViewBag` is `dynamic`. You need to cast it - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model_Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Model_List, "<<< CREATE NEW >>>", new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })`

Comment: [Light Bulb!] My bad! i thought the `SelectList()` portion was just designating to put whatever my `SelectList` from my Model was named. I did not realize that was a cast!

Comment: I'll address you other question in a few hours - hopefully that will boost it by a few million watts :)

Comment: Lol, thanks for all your help! :) I'm obviously pretty green at MVC so I appreciate being shown proper way to go about things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method which will insert the element as the first child, while `append` insert content after the last child:

> The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use `.append()`).

```
$('select.dropdown').prepend('<option>' + "<<< Add New >>>" + '</option');
```

**Update**
To use section you should do the following:

In your `_Layout.cshtml` add this:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

In your view use it like this:

```
@section Scripts 
{
    <script>some script</script>
}
```

You can place the `section` wherever you want in the view and it will render in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks! That works in console, but still not working when I load the page. I moved the script by itself at the very end of my `View`: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select.dropdown').prepend('<option>' + "<<< Add New >>>" + '</option');
    });
</script>`. It seems to be flagging as Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Comment: You need to create a section in the layout file and then use it to add custom scripts. The thing is that your current script is executed before jquery is loaded (as it's probably defined at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it now. I had my `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` & `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` at the bottom of my `_Layout.cshtml`, which as you said was causing my above script to load before `jQuery` was ever scripted in. On my layout file I now have the following all under the <title>: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` and no errs.

Comment: You should be aware of the consequences of putting the scripts on the top of the page. If you do that you page will not load until the scripts are loaded, so the approach with defining a custom section at the bottom of layout and using it in your views is better. I'll update the code

Comment: Instead of putting your scripts in the `title` tag, put them in the bottom of the page and put the `RenderSection` below them

Comment: Ok, but if I move all the above from just under my <title> to the bottom of my `_Layout.cshtml` page, then the script at the bottom of my `Edit.cshtml` doesn't function and generate the new option, since it loads before the main jQuery script......?

Comment: You should put it inside the `section {}` as I've shown

Comment: But I've got my scripts bundled, not in the individual script declarations like you've shown?

Comment: You write an individual script inside your `Edit` view, right? Just put it into the `section`.

Comment: Wait, sorry. I think I'm following now. Let me experiment and I'll get back with you.